# AD user login error using GDM-password with sssd?

Tags: permissions, login, password, gdm

We have a Ubuntu 18.04 machine that had an issue where AD users were unable to log in with their credentials. I found a error that pointed to a GPO that was causing issue. A quick search showed that adding `ad_gpo_ignore_unreadable = True` would fix the solution and it did. Users were able to logon properly.

Faster forward to today, and the issue is happening again. I've looked at `var/log/auth.conf` and found the following:

```
Oct 19 16:34:27 hostname gdm-password]: pam_unix(gdm-password:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost=  user=alice
Oct 19 16:34:27 hostname gdm-password]: pam_sss(gdm-password:auth): authentication success; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=/dev/tty1 ruser= rhost= user=alice
Oct 19 16:34:27 hostname gdm-password]: pam_sss(gdm-password:account): Access denied for user alice: 6 (Permission denied)
```

Any thoughts?